# Is it possible to print at certain coordinates with a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I'm learning batch for the fun of it (so I can make quick and simple games), and it would be great if I could print at certain coordinates. How do I do this? Can I do this? Something like gotoxy(x,y) in C++.

```
Example:
 ___________________
|                   |
|                   |
|    Print here     |
|                   |
|                   |
|___________________|
```

Comment: What batch processor/scripting environment are you trying to use?  What platform?

Comment: Windows 8, command prompt, written in Notepad++.

Comment: Try this http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ansi.php - specifically `Cursor Positioning`

Comment: That's pretty cool, however it's outdated. I've looked into it. ANSI was only functional on pre XP systems. Thanks for the find though, it was cool to learn about.